# Improve tabBar animation when hidden

Tags: ios, animation, uitabbar

I've think about how to make the tabBar 's hidden animation more elegant and smoothly:

Here is how I implement:
So I just want to improve the animation, while the tabBar is suddenly, you know, disappear and hidden.

```
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
  [self.tabBarController.tabBar setHidden:YES];
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
  [self.tabBarController.tabBar setHidden:NO];
}
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this method:

```
- (void)setTabBarHidden:(BOOL)tabBarHidden animated:(BOOL)animated
{
  if (tabBarHidden == _isTabBarHidden)
    return;

  CGFloat offset = tabBarHidden ? self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame.size.height : -self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame.size.height;

  [UIView animateWithDuration:animated ? 0.6 : 0.0
                        delay:0
       usingSpringWithDamping:0.7
        initialSpringVelocity:0.5
                      options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn|UIViewAnimationOptionLayoutSubviews
                   animations:^{
                     self.tabBarController.tabBar.center = CGPointMake(self.tabBarController.tabBar.center.x,
                                                                       self.tabBarController.tabBar.center.y + offset);
                   }
                   completion:nil];

  _isTabBarHidden = tabBarHidden;
}
```

Then you can call it like `[self setTabBarHidden:YES animated:YES]` and `[self setTabBarHidden:NO animated:YES]` to hide and show your bar, this will move it in and out of the screen instead of just make it instantly dissapear.

Don't forget to add a new bool property `isTabBarHidden` and also you can play with the values of the animation.

Comment: The flag `animated` is not used here.  Add `animation ? 0.6 : 0.0` to the animation duration. :)